# Invalidação de diversos caches eficientemente no Django

Tags: django

No meu projeto eu possuo o seguinte modelo:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    month = models.DateField('month', null=False, blank=False, db_index=True)
    kg = models.BigIntegerField('kg')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', related_name='items')
    // vários outros campos utilizados para filtrar
```

E eu tenho a `report_view` que retorna a soma de `kg` **por month** e **por tag** de acordo com `os filtros` fornecidos na query da `URL`.

Essa `view` retorna algo tipo isso:

```
--------------------------------
|Tag    |jan    |fev    |mar   |
--------------------------------
|Tag 1  |1000   |1500   |2000  |
--------------------------------
|Tag 2  |1235   |4652   |0     |
--------------------------------
```

Como minha tabela `Item` já tem mais de 4 milhões de registros e está sempre crescendo, minha `report_view` fica sempre no *cache*.

Até aí tudo bem.

**O problema é**: os usuários do site podem mudar as `tags` dos `Items` e sempre que isso ocorre é necessário invalidar as *caches*, mas eu gostaria de fazer isso de um modo mais *granulado*.

Por exemplo, se um usuário mudar a `tag` em um `Item` de `janeiro` isso deveria apenas invalidar os *caches* de `janeiro` (Eu prefiro que os *caches* sejam por mês do que por `tag` pois às vezes uma `tag` interfere na outra). Porém eu não sei quais são todas as `views` que foram pro `cache` porque existem milhares de possibilidades de diferentes filtros que alteram as `URL`.

O que eu consegui fazer até agora:

- Criar um `signal` que invalida todos os *caches* sempre que uma `tag` muda

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Item.tags.through)
def tags_changed(sender, **kwargs):
    cache.clear()
```

Porém isso limpa **tudo** o que não é bom..

Existe uma maneira de marcar os *caches* para que algo do tipo seja feito:

```
cache.filter('jan').clear()
```